# Adding parameters to init and create instance

Tags: python, class, object, parameters, pygame

I want to make two varaibles of my class dynamic, so they have different values depending of the diffuculty that is selected for the game. Did I do something wrong in the `__init__` or where is the problem? If I delete the two parameters `speed_top_border, speed_bottom_border` from the `__init__` and enter static values everything works perfectly fine.

```
# Obstacle class
class Obstacle(object):

    # Init
    def __init__(self, speed_top_border, speed_bottom_border):
        self.obstacleImg = 'rock.png'
        self.obstacleX = random.randint(700, 800)
        self.obstacleY = random.randint(0, ScreenHeight - 64)
        self.obstacleX_change = random.uniform(self.speed_top_border, self.speed_bottom_border)

# Keep window running (Infinite-Loop)
running = 1

# Menu-loop
while running == 1:

    # Insert Background
    screen1.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # Quit game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = 0

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            # Difficulty easy
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                speed_top_border = -1
                speed_bottom_border = -0.5

            # Start game
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                running = 2

# Game While-Loop
    while running == 2:

# Creation of instancet of class obstacle each iteration
        if timer1_current - timer1_start >= interval:
            timer1_start = time.time()  # Timer of start set to current time
            obstacle = Obstacle(speed_top_border, speed_bottom_border)  # Create instance of class obstacle
            obstacle_list.append(obstacle)  # Append instance to list
            print(obstacle)  # Print created instance for check
            score += 100 * score_multiplier  # Increase score
```

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\2DFlugzeugspiel\main.py", line 221, in <module>
    obstacle = Obstacle(speed_top_border, speed_bottom_border)  # Create instance of class obstacle
  File "C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\2DFlugzeugspiel\main.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.obstacleX_change = random.uniform(self.speed_top_border, self.speed_bottom_border)
AttributeError: 'Obstacle' object has no attribute 'speed_top_border'
```

Comment: And what is it exactly that doesn't work fine here? If you get an error, please include the complete error traceback in your question. If you don't get the expected behaviour, please explain what your actual vs expected behaviour is.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille oh sorry, I added it

Comment: Please always include the **complete** error traceback...

Comment: Also, note that you passed the `speed_top_border` to `__init__`, but you never stored it anywhere. You probably meant to create an attribute with `self.speed_top_border = speed_top_border`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thanks for the hint. I added the complete message now

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks, it works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never define `self.speed_top_border`, `self.speed_bottom_border` in your `__init__`, but try to use them in `self.obstacleX_change = random.uniform(self.speed_top_border, self.speed_bottom_border)`

If you want to have these attributes - define them, before using them

```
class Obstacle(object):

    def __init__(self, speed_top_border, speed_bottom_border):
        self.obstacleImg = 'rock.png'
        self.obstacleX = random.randint(700, 800)
        self.obstacleY = random.randint(0, ScreenHeight - 64)
        self.speed_top_border = speed_top_border
        self.speed_bottom_border = speed_bottom_border
        self.obstacleX_change = random.uniform(self.speed_top_border, self.speed_bottom_border)
```